# how to center column vertically in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a code that draws a table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Distribution of class categories}
    \label{tbl::Fam}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{3}{S[table-format=3.0]} @{}}
        \toprule
        Column&Algorithm&{min}&{max}&{std.dev.}\\
        \midrule
        age&Original &9&28&100\\
        &PrivBayes&2&95&96\\
        &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
        \addlinespace
        education\_level&Original&7&28&98\\
        &PrivBayes&2&6&96\\
        &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
        \midrule
        \addlinespace
        employer\_type&Original&13&2&10\\
        &PrivBayes&2&100&100\\
        &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
        \addlinespace
        marital\_status&Original&10&20&100\\
        &PrivBayes&2&6&100\\
        &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\            
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that it does not align {age, education_level, employer_type, marital_status} in a center of multirow vertically. Can you please help me?

Comment: So, basically, you want `{age, education_level, employer_type, marital_status}` to be lined up with `PrivBayes` and not with `Original`, right? Please confirm.

Comment: You don't use `\multirow`.

Comment: Yes definitely. I want {age, education_level, employer_type, marital_status} with the same level with `Original`

Comment: @user3104352 you're comment does confuse me a lot. I guess/hope you made a typo.

Comment: but table as you shown in question is better looking and logical structured than tables as you like to have ...

Comment: @Zarko the customer is always right :) You're right though, it is easier to comprehend the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `\multirow` from the `multirow`-package, they are vertically aligned. You didn't specify that this cell should be across several rows but inserted one cell with content and two empty cells. Note that with `\multirow` you still have to insert the empty cells in the other rows, though.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Distribution of class categories}
    \label{tbl::Fam}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{3}{S[table-format=3.0]} @{}}
        \toprule
        Column&Algorithm&{min}&{max}&{std.dev.}\\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}{*}{age}&Original &9&28&100\\
        &PrivBayes&2&95&96\\
        &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
        \addlinespace
        \multirow{3}{*}{education\_level}&Original&7&28&98\\
        &PrivBayes&2&6&96\\
        &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
        \midrule
        \addlinespace
        \multirow{3}{*}{employer\_type}&Original&13&2&10\\
        &PrivBayes&2&100&100\\
        &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
        \addlinespace
        \multirow{3}{*}{marital\_status}&Original&10&20&100\\
        &PrivBayes&2&6&100\\
        &ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\            
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No need to use the `multirow` package. Just place the items `{age, education_level, employer_type, marital_status}` one row below they are right now...

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per=slash, load=abbr}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Distribution of class categories}
\label{tbl::Fam}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{3}{S[table-format=3.0]} @{}}
\toprule
Column&Algorithm&{min}&{max}&{std.dev.}\\
\midrule
&Original &9&28&100\\
age&PrivBayes&2&95&96\\ % moved "age" down by 1 rows
&ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
\addlinespace
&Original&7&28&98\\
education\_level&PrivBayes&2&6&96\\
&ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
\addlinespace
\midrule
\addlinespace
&Original&13&2&10\\
employer\_type&PrivBayes&2&100&100\\
&ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
\addlinespace
&Original&10&20&100\\
marital\_status&PrivBayes&2&6&100\\
&ThirdAlg &10&90&50\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case there is no need for `multirow`, but if there are only two lines...

Comment: @Skillmon - Indeed, your observation applies for the code at hand. Since the OP didn't indicate that the number of rows per group might be even (say, 2) rather than 3, I didn't see the need to pull out the heavy artillery, *viz.*, the `multirow` package... :-)

Comment: As I said, it is not needed here indeed, but if another person stumbles across this site on his search for a solution, mine helps in any case, not just with odd row counts.